# Compile error in hidden module:Module04_ExportToSAPServer

Tags: excel

I use the windows10 laptop,and the EXCEL appears this kind of error, can you help me to provide a solution?
Compile error in hidden module:Module04_ExportToSAPServer.This error commonly occurs when code is incompatible with the version, platform, or architecture of this application.

Comment: If module is hidden (protected), it's better to ask its author to help solving the issue.

Comment: Most likely you are missing a reference - e.g. for SAPServer